# Merge csv with missing values and Unstructured Data set

Tags: r

Hi I am unable to merge csv files which are unstructured. Below is my code:

```
file1 = read.csv("fileone.csv",header=TRUE,skip=0)
file2 = read.csv("filetwo.csv",header=TRUE,skip=0)
```

I have data sets something like this:

```
 Data:file1                                   Date:file2
 City     State                              City    State
Boston      MA                              Dallas     TX
Seattle     WA                              Lowell     MA
Miami       FL
Chicago     IL
```

I want result like this:

```
  MergedData
City      State
Boston      MA                              
Seattle     WA                              
Miami       FL
Chicago     IL
Dallas      TX
Lowell      MA
```

Comment: is this `merge` or just `rbind(file1, file2)` ?

Comment: read this, it will help you: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/06/9-challenges-data-merging-subsetting-r-python-beginner/

Comment: @RonakShah thank you! i tried rbind(file1,file2) it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mergedFile =merge(file1,file2,all=TRUE,sort=FALSE)
```

Comment: It worked thank you!